# LWC: Only enable button if options are available

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, button, wire

I would like to enable/disable a button in LWC depending on if a list variable is empty or not. I know it's possible with a formula in Aura, is it doable in LWC? I have tried the below, but it doesn't work.

```
        <lightning-layout horizontal-align="space" vertical-align="end">
            <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small" flexibility="grow">
                <lightning-combobox
                    name="objects"
                    label="Objects"
                    value={selectedObject}
                    placeholder="Select Object"
                    options={options.data}
                    onchange={handleObjectChange}
                ></lightning-combobox>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item padding="horizontal-small">
                <lightning-button 
                    variant="brand"
                    label="Add"
                    title="Add object"
                    onclick={handleAdd}
                    class="slds-m-left_small"
                    disabled={empty(options.data)} <------ this line
                ></lightning-button>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
```

Comment: LWC, unlike [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm), doesn't have expression functions you can use in markup like `empty` or `if`. The logic will need to happen in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the property with the get method.

JS

```
get disableButton(){
    return !(this.options && this.options.data && this.options.data.length);
}
```

HTML

```
<lightning-button 
    variant="brand"
    label="Add"
    title="Add object"
    onclick={handleAdd}
    class="slds-m-left_small"
    disabled={disableButton}
></lightning-button>
```

Comment: What determines whether the "showButton" will be updated? Does the component know to watch the "options" variable?

Comment: The `get` makes it reactive. when the dependencies are updated it also gets updated. @fred

Comment: Either the logic is backwards here or you've misnamed the getter. In your code, if `showButton` is true, then disabled is true -- but if you want to show the button, you don't want to disable it. You probably want to rename that getter to `disableButton` and reverse the logic.

Comment: @jbyrd Makes sense! updated.

Comment: I think you'd want `return !(this.options && this.options.data && this.options.data.length);` ...and then I'll give it an upvote :)

Comment: @jbyrd Yes you are right OP has mentioned that they want to disable when list is empty. Updated the answer. Thanks

Comment: What is the difference between `this.options` and `this.options.data` ?

Comment: @Caroline When you create wired function property, it contains two things 1. data i.e. result of wired method(it can be apex/APIs) and the error contains errors if any. Check [wired service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about) for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get the "disabled" attribute to go away using this "disabled={disableButton}" approach. It works for disabling the button initially, but when my LWC controller is ready to enable the button the "disable" property never gets removed from the button ... just stays there as <button id="myButton" disabled .../>

Comment: FWIW here's what I had to do - this disabled={disableButton} approach just wouldn't work for me. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309627/how-to-get-and-set-the-attribute-in-lwc#comment551347_309629

Comment: @Christopher yes that is the way if you want `<button disabled >` instead of `<button disabled="true" >` format. Although in the first method the value stays there, its value is changed to disabled="false". and if you are trying to apply CSS then you need to consider that.

Comment: Thanks @RahulGawale. Yeah for some reason the "disabled" would never go away after I got it on the lightning-button. Whether I set it to "disabled=true" or used setAttribute or removeAttribute. Very odd. For now my custom html data property approach works - though I feel like I'm doing it a weird way.