# How can I disable a LWC button only if the Omniscript fields are empty?

Tags: lightning-web-components, button, vlocity

In Step 1 on an Omniscript, I have two text elements: "neighborhood" and "city".

There is also the "Search" button made in LWC. I need it to be disabled only if the fields "neighborhood" OR "city" are empty, but I'm not getting it... Can anyone help me? Here's what I tried to do initially:

**The omniscript**
[image]

**Preview**
[image]

**searchButtonLWC.html**

```
<template>
 <div>
  <lightning-button
            variant="destructive" 
            label="Search"
            onclick={handleClick}
            disabled={disableButton}
            class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
  </lightning-button>
 </div>
</template>
```

**​searchButtonLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin';
 
export default class searchButtonLWC extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
 
    @api neighborhood;
    @api city;
   
    _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
    _actionUtilClass;
 
    connectedCallback() {
        this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
    }
 
    handleClick() {
    }   
 
    get requiredFieldsFilled(){
        return (this.neighborhood && this.city);
    }
 
    disableButton(){
        return !(this.requiredFieldsFilled());
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
    get requiredFieldsFilled(){
        return (this.neighborhood && this.city);
    }
 
    disableButton(){
        return !(this.requiredFieldsFilled());
    }
```

To

```
    requiredFieldsFilled(){
        return (this.neighborhood && this.city);
    }
 
    get disableButton(){
        return !(this.requiredFieldsFilled());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a getter property here and let lifecycle take care of calling it internally when any change in attribute is detected.

I quickly wrote a small example for you. The getter `disableButton` will always get called when it sees a change in `neighborhood` or `city` and will make it enabled if either of these have value and disable it when both are `undefined` || `null` || `""`

For eg:

HTML:

```
<template>

    <lightning-input type="text" label="Search neighborhood" name="neighborhood" value={neighborhood} onchange={handleTextChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Search city" name="city" value={city} onchange={handleTextChange}></lightning-input>
    <div>
        <lightning-button
                variant="destructive"
                label="Search"
                onclick={handleClick}
                disabled={disableButton}
                class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
export default class Disablesearchbox extends LightningElement {

    neighborhood;
    city;

    
    handleTextChange (event){
        if(event.target.name==='neighborhood'){
            this.neighborhood = event.target.value;
        }else if(event.target.name==='city'){
            this.city = event.target.value;
        }
    }
    handleClick() {
    }

    get disableButton(){
        return ((this.neighborhood === undefined || this.neighborhood === null || this.neighborhood === "") &&
            (this.city === undefined || this.city === null || this.city === ""));
        
    }

}
```

Comment: but in your case, the fields are inside the LWC. On mine they are in Omniscript... I guess It makes a little difference...

Comment: So in that case, is there an event which gets triggered when `neighborhood` or `city`  is changing, I believe as these are @api attributes, these should change. This you can write something similar to getter attribute above.